# Django process_response() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: django, django-middleware

I am trying to write some middleware for my django app. In the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/middleware/#process-response) it defines process response with two parameters, request and response. But when I try to write some middleware I get an exception thrown:

```
Type Error:
process_response() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Here is my code:

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

```
class Middleware(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        print('processing response')
        ref = request.GET.get('ref','')
        if ref:
            response.set_cookie('ref', ref, max_age=3600*24*365)
        return response

    def process_request(request):
        print('processing request')
        print(request.META['PATH_INFO'])
        ref = request.COOKIES.get('ref','')
        if ref:
            request.GET['ref'] = ref
        return None
```

But then a peculiar thing happened. I commented out the process_request function. And then I got 0 errors. When I uncommented the process_request function I then got the error:

```
process_request() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This is starting to seem like random behavior..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `self` in the `process_request` definition.

Comment: Ah yes, the documentation doesn't say anything about defining 'self'. But I was playing around with that anyway. But why would the docs not mention 'self'? Is the 'self' just implied.

Comment: That's how normal methods on class instances work - they always receive the instance they're called on as their first argument. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects for details.

Answer (score 0):

I got here following the error message "takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" although in my case, I'm actually providing 2 positional arguments and 3 are desired. This is for anyone else who is in the same situation. Django 2.2.5 for me.

change

```
def has_add_permission(self, request):
    return False
```

to:

```
def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return False
```

I probably could have found this by looking at the django source, instead I found it here:

https://github.com/celiao/django-rest-authemail/issues/32#issuecomment-800859698

Comment: Hi Martin, sorry about the multiple  posts and I appreciate the guidance for how to do this next time.  It was difficult to find an answer to this one.